# How do I plot certain columns using xmgrace in the terminal?

Tags: plot, terminal, xmgrace

I want to write a bash script to automate the plotting of data, using a plotting tool called xmgrace, but I want to be able to select which columns are plotted.

Say in my data file I have 3 columns, with the x and y data in the 1st and 3rd columns. How do I plot x against y when the data is formatted this way?

I tried `xmgrace -bxy [1:3] data` but that didn't work, it said `No block data read` and treated the second column as the y values.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct syntax for this kind of problem is

```
xmgrace -block file -bxy 1:3
```

This will

1. Read the file as a block file
2. Plot the 3rd column against the 1st column.

Comment: FYI, `-bxy 0:3` plots the 3rd column vs the row number.

Comment: Also, for set types involving more than two columns, such as xydy (x,y and errorbars), the syntax is  `xmgrace -block file -settype xydy -bxy 1:2:3`.

Answer (score 4):

Another flexible way of accomplishing the same thing is to use `awk` or `cut`:

```
awk '{print $1,$3}' data | xmgrace -
cut -f1,3 data | xmgrace -
```